# What did I do that the whole layout screen isn’t showing anything? I can’t find the camera

Tags: camera

Everything is still there when I go into modelling,shading,animation, rendering etc but just not showing anything in layout(the grids are gone too). The camera was working normal too…Can anyone please tell me how to fix the display back to normal?
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Try this: select an object in the outliner and View -> Frame Selected

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Comment: Try switching out of Rendered view (top-right icon) to Solid mode (white circle icon) then centre your selected object with the . (period key) on the numpad.